# Using a string as a RID with SQL Commands

Tags: orientdb

Using the Java api on an Orient-DB 2.0 rc1. **Is it possible to use a string as a RID?**

Documentation : https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Update#example-3-add-a-value-into-a-collection
 more specifiaclly the section `SQL Commands`

JSON received:

```
{
    userRID:"#100:100",
    group:"someCode"
}
```

JAVA CODE (xtend script):

```
def addUserInGroup(Message<JsonObject> message){
    val params = new JsonObject() => [
        putString("userId", message.body().getString("userRID"));
        putString("code", message.body().getString("group"));
    ]

    var queryCommand= "update Table add users=:userId where code=:code";

    Map<String, Object> paramsFormatted = params.toMap();

    database.command( new OCommandSQL(queryCommand) ).execute(paramsFormatted);
}
```

Table structure :

```
users : linklist (user object)
code : string
```

When I run the following commands in the studio they all work :

```
update Table add users=(Select @rid from User where @rid=#100:100) where code='someCode'
update Table add users=#100:100 where code='someCode'
```

But none of these command work in the API. I'm guessing there is something wrong in way I'm using the RID.

```
SEVERE: Exception in Java verticle
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #29: Found unexpected keyword '=:USERID' while it was expected '[=]'. Use UPDATE <class>|cluster:<cluster>> [SET|ADD|PUT|REMOVE|INCREMENT|CONTENT {<JSON>}|MERGE {<JSON>}] [[,] <field-name> = <expression>|<sub-command>]* [LOCK <NONE|RECORD>] [UPSERT] [RETURN <COUNT|BEFORE|AFTER>] [WHERE <conditions>]
Command: update SecureAccess add users=:userId where code=:code
-------------------------------------^
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLAbstract.throwSyntaxErrorException(OCommandExecutorSQLAbstract.java:89)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.parser.OBaseParser.parserRequiredKeyword(OBaseParser.java:317)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.parseAddFields(OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.java:605)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.java:129)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.java:59)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:56)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:37)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1150)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:63)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1179)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:385)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:216)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:65)

janv. 07, 2015 8:45:17 AM org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate error
SEVERE: Exception in Java verticle
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #29: Found unexpected keyword '=:USERID' while it was expected '[=]'. Use UPDATE <class>|cluster:<cluster>> [SET|ADD|PUT|REMOVE|INCREMENT|CONTENT {<JSON>}|MERGE {<JSON>}] [[,] <field-name> = <expression>|<sub-command>]* [LOCK <NONE|RECORD>] [UPSERT] [RETURN <COUNT|BEFORE|AFTER>] [WHERE <conditions>]
Command: update SecureAccess add users=:userId where code=:code
-------------------------------------^
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLAbstract.throwSyntaxErrorException(OCommandExecutorSQLAbstract.java:89)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.parser.OBaseParser.parserRequiredKeyword(OBaseParser.java:317)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.parseAddFields(OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.java:605)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.java:129)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLUpdate.java:59)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:56)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.parse(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:37)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1150)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:63)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1179)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:385)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:216)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:65)
```

Comment: I think the problem is parameters in sub queries
see here
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/1069

Comment: I tried without the subquery, but without sucess, but it does work in the studio

Answer (score 1):

I think You should try something like :

```
 putString("userId", new ORecordId(message.body().getString("userRID")));
```